# How can I dynamically call a variable in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, variables, dynamic-variables

I am creating a new variable name by combining existing variables, however, I cannot find a way to reference the new variable names dynamically through using my existing variables.

```
$count = 1
New-Variable -Name "Jobname$Count"
```

I am expecting to get "Jobname1" when I resolve dynamically with $JobName$Count.

I have tried different combinations of referencing the variable but none of them worked:

```
$JobName$($Count)
$JobName"$Count"
$JobName"$($Count)"
$JobName"($Count)"
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Your first example __is creating__ the variable `$jobName1`. I assume you want to dynamically call it and get it's value?

Comment: that's right, the problem is when I try to dynamically call it.
EDIT: I see your point, i just changed the title of the post. thnx.

Comment: So, something like: `Get-Variable -Name "$Jobname$count"`?

Comment: **_generally speaking_ ... you otta not do that.** [*grin*] use a collection and then address the objects in that collection. hashtables are REALLY good for finding something by name if the name is unique. that structure is nearly ideal for looking up stored things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already know how to dynamically create a new variable, either by using `New-Variable` or `Set-Variable`. If you want to dynamically get your variable you can either use `Get-Variable` or `$ExecutionContext.SessionState.PSVariable.Get(..)` or a much easier way would be using `-PassThru`:

```
$count = 1
$var = New-Variable -Name "Jobname$Count" -Value 'example' -PassThru
$var

Name                           Value
----                           -----
Jobname1                       example

Get-Variable "Jobname$Count"

Name                           Value
----                           -----
Jobname1                       example

$ExecutionContext.SessionState.PSVariable.Get("Jobname$Count")

Name                           Value
----                           -----
Jobname1                       example
```